# Auto Detech in Google Speech API

Tags: android, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I want to detect the Spoken language out of two selected language as an Interpreter Mode. But, the Google Speech API doesn't support auto detection, while the Google Translate App auto detects the Language for translation.
 Can anyone tell how to achieve it.

[image]